# How to map a drive with read only access in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions

I need help with setting folder permissions when accessing folders from across my network (vs. logging into a Win 7 machine locally.)

Here is my scenario.

I have several Windows 7 Pro pc's.  My main machine is called "FamilyStorage" and it's similar to a file server.  No one actually logs into this machine locally, except me.

Connected to this machine are multiple hard drives with different data on each drive.  One drive is music.  Another is Pictures.  A third is software, ETC.  I then share each drive.

For my wife, myself and my son, i created custom login scripts which are used on our respective PC's.  It's basically a Notepad file that i rename to .BAT.  For example:  For example:  LoginDad.bat or LoginMom.bat or LoginSon.bat

Myself and my Wife, I map all drives shared on "FamilyStorage".  For my son though, I map only to his home-drive and to the "Pictures" drive.

I'm concerned about him being able to delete files and I'd like to change his access to READ ONLY.

Since I am not on a domain, I cannot set permissions on "FamilyStorage" based on machine name.  In addition, since we do not log in locally, setting individual user permission also does not resolve my issue.

I am hoping there is a way I could take my Login Script file and add some kind of switch which would cause the mapping to be in a read only mode.  For example:  NET USE P:  //familyStorage/Pictures -ro

I know that's wrong but hopefully it makes sense as to what i'm trying to do.

At the end of the day... when I log into my pc and my wife into hers... we both need full access to the Picture drive mapping and we have it.  At the same time, I would like to map P for my son as well but with him, he gets read only.  And this is the part i'm not able to do.

I really do not want to have to remote control into my "FamilyStorage" machine every time I want to copy pictures down or rename folders.  There must be another way.  I also do not want to have to duplicate this Picture drive... because then i'm maintaining 2 sets of files and it's taking up twice the storage space.  This is the only other alternative I have found.  Duplicate the drive and give it a name "PicturesSon".  Then I set the drive to READ ONLY and I map to that drive instead in his login script but again, the issue with this is now i'm maintaining another drive and using up all that extra storage space.  And there is a lot of pictures and video files... TB's worth.

Thanks for allowing my question.  Sorry if his is a bit wordy.

T

Answer (score 2):

On your server, share it twice:

```
net share foo_r=c:\foo\test /GRANT:EVERYONE,READ
net share foo_rw=c:\foo\test /GRANT:EVERYONE,FULL
```

And then modify your batch files to point to the desired share type when mapping the drive letter.

Obviously this relies on your child not eventually *manually* browsing the network shares or attempting access using the network path instead of the mapped drive.

Comment: Boy, the answer is so simple it's almost embarrassing!  Thank you.  :)    I've also been reading that using homegroups would work also.  I can set up the homegroup, set permissions based on that.  But, your suggestion is easier!  Once again, thanks.

Comment: No problem. Its not always obvious: the GUI only allows one share.

Comment: @terster would batch files that mount those shares for your examples then mount either the name `foo_r` or `foo_rw`, depending on whether they mount the read-write share or the read-only share?

What exactly might batch files that mount those shares contain?